# 16 bit wchar_t support in linux and gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, wchar-t

I'm working on a cross platform project that complies with  the `-fshort-wchar` flag 
so the `wchar_t` type is 2 byte. On Windows that's fine but on Linux the means no libc functions like `printf` or `fprintf`.

I've been looking for a good solution for some time now and frankly getting a little desperate.

Does anyone have a good idea except avoid using libc functions altogether?

Comment: If you're working with wide characters, you must use [`wprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wprintf) instead of `printf`.

Comment: the problem is that in linux (gcc) wprintf only works with 32 bit wchar_t

Comment: That's because the representation of `wchar_t` is dependent on platform and locale. The one your program uses must match the one your libc supports. Read [this](http://icu-project.org/docs/papers/unicode_wchar_t.html) for some more info.

Comment: is there any why to get a libc implementation that works with 16 bit wchar_t ?

Answer (score 0):

This inside an `#ifdef` might help (i haven't tested it though):

```
typedef __u16 wchar_t16;
```